# Can't change my graphic card from intel to nvdia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

So i am really new to ubuntu, i used to use windows before and with steam proton i swiched to ubuntu 18.04. But there is a problem that i can't fix, my computer has 2 graphic cards and it use intel graphic card intead of nvidia and i dont know how to fix it...

so i hear some ss that can be usefull:

[lspci | grep VGA and sudo lshw -C video and glxinfo | grep OpenGL is in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ttti.png)

[nvidia settings is in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajfL4.png)

[my computer settings/about is in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hhtp.png)

[software and updates are in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqfGJ.png)

Comment: Did you check the BIOS/UEFI settings for any related to video?  When you login, do you select xorg instead of wayland (under the little gear next to login name)? Which Ubuntu release are you running?  Did you install the Nvidia driver from the Software and Updates/Additional drivers tab?  You should cut and paste text info in your question (maybe with code tags) to make it easier to read.

Comment: @ubfan1 okay like i said i am new to ubuntu, so i dont know how to check if i select xorg or wayland, i am not using double boot by the way, i googled "check the BIOS/UEFI settings" and with the information from there i find out that my computer use UEFI but i am not sure if it answers your question, my ubuntu version is 18.04 and yes i downloaded nvdia from additinal drivers and from nvdia settings i did click to nvdia to use it.

Comment: @ubfan1 is there something wrong with the images that i put do i need to change them to be more usefull?

Comment: Nvidia proprietary driver is not installed. This may be a bug in a kernel or driver. You are not the first who meets this problem. You can try to reinstall a driver using CLI and see what is wrong.

Comment: Terminal text output should be cut and pasted instead of an image taken to allow searches and to help people with slow internet connections see the question faster.  Pilot6 is right, driver may be present, but not used. Check all files in /etc/modprobe.d for any line that is  "blacklist nvidia" (except blacklist nvidiafb is OK). Maybe load the module with sudo modprobe nvidia and see if the driver show up in the lshw output (like where the i915 is for the Intel GPU).